# Changing Checkbox state before firing click manually

Tags: jquery, checkbox, triggers, click, checked

I am using an old version of JQuery, and I need my `Checkboxes` to change their `checked` state before executing their `onclick` method when `click` is triggered programatically.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb_1" name="cb_1" onclick="Write(this)" />
<input type="text" id="tb_1" name="tb_1" />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="cb_2" name="cb_2" onclick="Write(this)" />
<input type="text" id="tb_2" name="tb_2" />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="cb_3" name="cb_3" onclick="Write(this)" />
<input type="text" id="tb_3" name="tb_3" />
<br />
<input type="button" id="bt" name="bt" value="Write All Checkboxes" onclick="WriteAll()" />
```

JS:

```
function Write($this)
{
    var _Selected = $($this).is(':checked');
    $('#' + $this.id.replace('c', 't')).val(_Selected);
}

function WriteAll() 
{
    $('[id^="cb_"]').each(function() 
    {
        if(!$(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $(this).trigger('click');            
        }
    });
}
```

As explained in [this ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10827),

> When a user click on a `Checkbox` with a click listener, it first flips the `checked` state and then fires the event. When a developer initiates a click on a `Checkbox` with jQuery, it first fires the event and then flips the `checked` state.

This kind of behaviour is fixed on JQuery > 1.8.3, see:

[Jquery 1.9.1](http://jsfiddle.net/tor171vt/8/)

[JQuery 1.8.3](http://jsfiddle.net/tor171vt/7/)

But it is not an option to change JQuery version for me, hence does someone have any idea?

Comment: Why not just use proper onchange event and also get rid of onclick handlers?

Comment: Could you develop further? JQuery/JS is still new for me.

Comment: set the checked state instead of trigger click, then call `Write`

Comment: @charlietfl Changed `$(this).trigger('click');` by `$(this).attr('checked', true); Write(this);` and it works! Not sure this is good programming though.

Comment: sure it is, no need to trigger an event. If version you use supports `prop()` would use that instead of `attr()`

Comment: Too old to use `prop()` unfortunately. I tried @dfsq method, and it works fine too. Could someone tell me which one is better?